# Android, How to use the layout-port when it is layout-tr?

Tags: android, android-studio, layout, screen

Language (layout-sq, layout-tr ) and (screen position) layout-port, layout-landscape

How will the screen and language hierarchy work?

There are 4 different layouts

1- layout-sq main_activity

2- layout-tr main_activity

2- layout-port main_activity

2- layout-landscape main_activity

Should I inject language options into layout-port? but how ?